# asynchronous error catcher wrapper function causing my returned promise to be undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am building an api and am trying to create some cookies using `req.cookie`.

Originally i was encountering an in issue in that the cookies were not all being set before the response was sent out in my scynchronous code:

```
const createTokensAndCookies = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const promises = [];
    promises.push(jwtToken.sign({ id: req.user._id }));
    promises.push(jwtRefreshToken.create());
    promises.push(csrfToken.create());
    const tokens = await Promise.all(promises);
    //create coookies
    jwtCookie.create(req, res, tokens[0]);
    jwtRefreshCookie.create(req, res, tokens[1]);
    csrfCookie.create(req, res, tokens[2]);

});
```

In an route handler i then called this function and in the next line called `res.send()`.

To fix the issue i made `createTokensAndCookies` return a promise. So my code as it stands is:

```
const createTokensAndCookies = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const promises = [];
    promises.push(jwtToken.sign({ id: req.user._id }));
    promises.push(jwtRefreshToken.create());
    promises.push(csrfToken.create());
    const tokens = await Promise.all(promises);
    //create coookies
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        jwtCookie.create(req, res, tokens[0]);
        jwtRefreshCookie.create(req, res, tokens[1]);
        csrfCookie.create(req, res, tokens[2]);
        resolve();
    });
});
```

The route handler:

```
exports.signUp = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    //get only certain variables out of req object
    const { body } = req;

    const user = await User.create({
        name: body.name,
        email: body.email,
        password: body.password,
        passwordConfirmation: body.passwordConfirmation,
    });
    req.user = user;
    createTokensAndCookies(req, res).then(() => {
        res.status(201).json({
            status: 'success',
        });
    });
});
```

And the `catchAsync` wrapper:

```
module.exports = (fn) => (req, res, next) => {
    fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
};
```

I am now getting the following error:
`Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Interestingly, when i remove the `catchAsync` wrapper everything works and the response isn't sent until all cookies are created.

Does anyone know how i can do this whilst keeping the `catchAsync` warpper? An explanation of why removing the `catchAsync` wrapper solves the issue would also be great.

Comment: "*To fix the issue i made `createTokensAndCookies` return a promise*" - the `async` function already **did** return a promise (it was using `await`), adding `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { … resolve(); });` does change absolutely nothing.

Comment: "*Does anyone know how i can do this whilst keeping the `catchAsync` warpper?*" - no, that makes no sense. Why would you want to keep it around the `createTokensAndCookies` definition? You should **only** use `catchAsync` around the route handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error seems to happen on this line:

```
createTokensAndCookies(req, res).then(() => {
```

The problem is that `createTokensAndCookies()` doesn't return anything. A simple fix that solves this particular problem might be that you change it like this to return a promise:

```
module.exports = (fn) => (req, res, next) => {
    return fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
};
```

However, I think the main problem is that you are using `catchAsync` inside `createTokensAndCookies`. Note that you are actually passing a function with only 2 parameters where 3 are expected. Catching twice seems redundant. You can and should just pass on the promise returned from `createTokensAndCookies` (without the `catchAsync`) inside the route handler. So remove the `catchAsync`:

```
const createTokensAndCookies = async (req, res) => {
    const promises = [];
    promises.push(jwtToken.sign({ id: req.user._id }));
    promises.push(jwtRefreshToken.create());
    promises.push(csrfToken.create());
    const tokens = await Promise.all(promises);
    //create cookies
    jwtCookie.create(req, res, tokens[0]);
    jwtRefreshCookie.create(req, res, tokens[1]);
    csrfCookie.create(req, res, tokens[2]);
};
```

And change the route handler like this:

```
exports.signUp = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    // ...
    return createTokensAndCookies(req, res).then(() => {
        res.status(201).json({
            status: 'success',
        });
    });
});
```

I suspect you want to keep the `catchAsync` in `createCookiesAndTokens` because you are using it somewhere else as a route handler. If this is the case, just wrap it in a `catchAsync` there. This way `createCookiesAndTokens` actually returns a promise that will fail when something goes wrong. This is what one would expect when reading the code and it makes the function more reusable.